# Properly copying data around in C#

Tags: c#, deep-copy, copying

I'm working on some simulation code in C#, and I have some code along the lines of:

```
public void predict(Point start, Point end)
{
    end.velocity = start.velocity + dt * end.acceleration;
    end.position = start.position + dt * end.velocity;
}
```

Where position, velocity, acceleration are some vector data types I defined with associated operators.

As well as code where I'm doing:

```
StartPoint = EndPoint;
EndPoint = CurrentPoint;
```

With the *Points being instances of Points that have several primitive (double) and non-primitive (Vector) data types.

I'm running into the (obvious) issue that the above code, most likely will simply just set StartPoint to point to the data that was previously EndPoint, and EndPoint will point to CurrentPoint.

Meaning, if I modify CurrentPoint again I'll end up accidentally modifying EndPoint.

In C++ this is simple to prevent since I can define my assignment operator to do a deep copy of the underlying data within my Point objects. How can I prevent this in C#?

Thanks for any help!

Edit: The Vector class is defined as

```
[Serializable]
public class Vector
{
    private Double[] data = new Double[Constants.Dimensions];

    ... snip ...

    public static Vector operator +(Vector lhs, Vector rhs)
    {
        Vector result = new Vector();
        for (UInt32 i = 0; i < Constants.dimensions; i++)
            result[i] = lhs[i] + rhs[i];
        return result;
    }

    lots more code here 
}
```

Comment: I assume Point is a class, not a struct?  If all it's members are value types, have you considered making it a value type as well?

Comment: @Bubbafat: I have some other classes that just contain primitives and the Vector (which is composed of primitives). If I convert said classes to struct, as well as Vector, would this allow me to do assignments that do a plain deep copy instead of simply making two objects point to the same memory?

Comment: Copying a value type always creates a copy of the value type (as opposed to a reference type which just copies the reference).  Before just copying everything you need to consider the other implications of doing this (performance, boxing, memory, stack usage, etc) but it would be a very simple way to avoid the deep copy if these are types that are logically value types, not reference types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the nastiest problems with the C# design IMHO.

If 'Point' is a struct (value), then a memberwise copy will be made, so `x = y` will make an *independent* copy of y. But if it is a class (reference), `x = y` will simply point the reference x to the same storage used for y, so the two will simply become different 'aliases' for the same data.

The two solutions I know of for your issue are:

- Use a struct. This will give you the value-type behaviour that you expect for maths classes. To keep your code efficient you may then need to pass by reference everywhere to avoid the structs being copied continually.
- Use a class, but be very very careful when using = to make sure you retain an independent copy of the data. You'll need to change `x = y` to something else, e.g. `x = new Point(y);`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use Clone(), and then implement the deep-copy how you need it?

```
StartPoint = EndPoint; 
EndPoint = (Point)CurrentPoint.Clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass by reference. Your methods are currently passing by value, meaning the value of your variables are being copied. The method will always be working with a copy of the data.

To pass by reference do the following:

```
public void predict(ref Point start, ref Point end)
{
    end.velocity = start.velocity + dt * end.acceleration;
    end.position = start.position + dt * end.velocity;
}
```

You will then have to call the method with the ref keyword like so:

```
predict(ref start, ref end);
```

Comment: This is only true if "Point" is a value type. (The OP implies that it is a class, not a struct).